# How do I delay passing props until setState() is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function called `renderLayers` which goes over each object in `filterState` and copy ones with `checked` property set to `true`

```
  const [layers, setLayers] = useState([]);
  (...)
  const renderLayers = () => {
        const newLayers = []; 
        filterState.map(filter => (filter.checked && 
                          newLayers.push(filter.linkedTo)
        ));  
        setLayers(newLayers);
      }
```

Then I have a component takes `layers` array as a prop. However, my code passes it before `setLayers` finishes its job.

```
<Component layers={layers}/>
```

In this case, how can I tell my program to wait until `setLayers()` is done? If I use a conditional rendering such as `<Component layers={layers.length > 0 && layers}`, will there be the case which `layers` still has a previous value and pass it before `setLayer()`?

Comment: *"However, my code passes it before setLayers finishes its job."* That doesn't seem possible based on your description of what the code does. Please provide a more complete example. When/where/when is `renderLayers` called? *"will there be the case which layers still has a previous value and pass it before setLayer()"* Really depends on how your component works over all. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ask the program to 'wait` per se, because this doesn't solve the core problem: what should be shown to the user?

What you can do, is pass a default value in the event that `layers` is empty:

```
<Component layers={layers.length > 0 ? layers : /*Some default value*/}/>
```

Or, inside `Component`, you can simply do nothing if `layers` is empty. When `layers` is updated, since it's passed to `Component`, `Component` will completely re-render anyway. This method is almost always preferred, as it keeps separates concerns better.

Example:

```
const Component = props => {
    if props.layers && props.layers.lengh > 0 {
        return <Stuff/>
    } else {
        return <Loading/>
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the logic inside of the component as it is from a library.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

```js
<Component layers={layers.length > 0 ? layers : null} />
```

If there's potential for `renderLayers` to result in an empty array, and you want to pass that empty array to `Component`, you might want to instead initialize `layers` as `null` instead:

```js
const [layers, setLayers] = useState(null)

// ...

return <Component layers={layers} />
```

This way while the `layers` prop gets set, it's `null` until `setLayers` is called with a different value.

If, as you say, `layers` can have a prior value that you don't want to render, you now have additional state in your application for determining whether or not `layers` should be passed down. This smells a lot like dirty tracking to me, but a simple solution might be just to switch `layers` to be an object with a state on it (you don't want to separate out the state here because multiple calls to setX can result in out-of-sync renders).

```js
const [layers, setLayers] = useState({ data: [], ready: false })

const renderLayers = () => {
  // ...
  setLayers({ data: ["example"], ready: true })
}

return <Component layers={layers.ready ? layers.data : null} />
```

Comment: what about the case that `layers` has a previous value therefore it is not empty?

Comment: Wouldn't it still cause the same issue as the value in `ready` property will remain true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering:

```
{layers.length > 0 && <Component layers={layers} />}
```

The `Component` will not be rendered unless there are something in `layers`.